# Map nested JSON (Mongo ATLAS) to SQL [Azure Data Factory]

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I want to map nested json to sql table (Microsoft SSMS)
[image]

**Source** is a Dataset of MongoAtlas &
**Sink** is a Dataset of Azure SQL Database Managed Instance

I am able to map parentArray using collection reference.
but not able to select child under it.
also childArrays are kind of scalar arrays (they don't have any keys)

Note : I tried the option **Map complex values to string**
but it is putting the values in column cell like ["ABC", PQR] which I dont want
is there any way to map it ?

Expected output for Table : childarray2
[image]

Comment: Hello @Agratu, Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: Basically I have 4 tables -> 1) Main 2) Main_ParentArray, 3) Main_ParentArray_ChildArray1 4) Main_ParentArray_ChildArray2 -------------------Parent_Id     Child 1
PA1              ABC
PA2              ABC
PA2              PQR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in ADF, Copy Activity supports mapping of arrays for only 1 level.
There is not way to map nested arrays.

For this I had to use Data flows.
Limitation was, we cannot use mongoDB/mongo Atlas as a input source in Data flow, so the workaround was

1. Convert Mongo To Azure Blob JSON (Copy Activity Task)
2. Use Azure Blob JSON files as a input source and then SQL tables as sink

Note: You can select this option to delete you blob files, to save storage space
[image]